# why cant i increase my heap size?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm, heap-memory

im using jdk 1.8.0_25 and im trying to work with a big database. it weights about 2gb.
i run the program trough eclipse.
i use 64bit java version on 64bit windows 7.
got 8gb ram.
everytime i try connectiong to it , i get java heap errors... so i tried increasing my heap size and i didnt make it!
visualVM says my max is still 2gb.

what i did was - control panel> programs > java > java > view.
ive added -Xmx6g parameter to my jdk (and im sure its the right jdk) but still nothing works.

any other suggestions on how to increase my heap size?

EDIT: 
here is the failing code line. just to make you guys sure that its not the code failing.

```
try {

        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/Work/currentFolder/reallyBigDB.mdb");
```

conn = ...... is the failing line.

Comment: What does "ive added -Xmx6g parameter to my jdk" mean?

Comment: Not to mention that you most likely don't want to read the whole database in memory to process it.

Comment: as said in the other comment -  
"ive added -Xmx6g parameter to my jdk" = entered the parameter -Xmx6g as a runtime parameter.

right now my program fails while creating the connection , not even loading the DB into a resultset . if you have any idea about improving this step , i would like to hear about it.

Comment: Show us the code where you're creating the `Connection`.

Comment: edited - 
its in the question now

Answer (score 1):

From [Ucanaccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) home page (first hit on Google).

> When dealing with large databases and using the default memory
>   settings (i.e., with Driver Property memory=true), it is recommended
>   that users allocate sufficient memory to the JVM using the -Xms and
>   -Xmx options. Otherwise it's needed to set Driver Property memory=false (Connection
>   conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://c:/pippo.mdb;memory=false");)

Now obviously you have another problem, the heap size. That's an eclipse issue. You could compile it in Eclipse and run it on the command line, giving the memory parameters there. That's at least a surefire way to make sure the parameters are correct.

Nevertheless, unless you absolutely have to load a huge chunk of data into memory, you usually don't want to. Luckily Ucanaccess has that parameter.

Comment: You also would have gotten an answer a lot faster if you had given all the **relevant** information: that you're using Ucanaccess to read an .mdb.

Answer (score 0):

To increase the heap size of the JVM when using Eclispe:

Window -> Preferences -> Java ->Installed JRE

Then select the JRE you are using, and click Edit and enter the argument for the JVM in *Default VM arguments*

PS: As already mentioned in the comment section, you should not load the entire DB in memory, so it may be a better idea to review your code instead for increasing the heap

Comment: "ive added -Xmx6g parameter to my jdk" =  entered the parameter             -Xmx6g as a runtime parameter.


i tried going to add heap size trough  preferences in eclipse and still looks like max heap is 2g.

can you tell me how am i supposed to work with such a big DB if i shouldnt load the entire db?

Comment: "still looks like max heap is 2g" how can you tell ? You dont have to load the DB to work with it, just make request to query the data you need at each time. Seeing your comment in the question, there is probably something wrong with your code,(and not with the settings of the heap). You should open a new question with the code and the error

Comment: i will edit the code part that fails in a minute... just saying that this code part works for every other (smaller) database... it fails only on this database and the problem is surely heap size reaching the limits.

i monitor the jvm using visualVM .

Answer (score 0):

Other two parameters alternative to memory=false that may be useful are:

skipIndexes=true (it avoids memory occupation due to indexes that aren't integrity constraints)

Lobscale=1 if the db size is due to blob/ole data. In this specific case both the load time and the memory occupation will be drammatically reduced.

They have been both introduced with the 2.0.9.4.